# Sign in with LinkedIn: Connection Issues (?)

Tags: linkedin-api

We have a "sign in with linked in" button on our website. From time to time, we see the following screen instead of the screen for email/password:

[image: error message]

This translates to: "We are sorry, an error occured. We had troutble setting up the connection".

This screen is 100% from linkedin... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

do you get a pop-up or do you get redirected to another page ?
maybe something goes wrong when using a redirection. We use pop-up's and have never came across anything like this.

Also note that you are displaying your client-ID in the URL. maybe blurr that out..

Comment: Alright... We are not using popups right now, just a redirect to linkedin. I'll check how to have the login process in a popup. Actually I thought that the page to which I redirect needs to redirect afterwards again to my system - thought this would not be possible because of CORS etc.